# Diagonal Lines in HTML in 8 different directions

Tags: html, css, lines, diagonal

Through a JAVA program, I am generating a Word Search Puzzle in HTML (using table / tr / td options).

I am trying to generate another table showing the solution to that puzzle. For example, as shown here.

http://www.puzzles.ca/wordsearch/kids_fourth_of_july_solution.html

Is it possible to generate such shapes? (if not, I can live with drawing the LINES to show the solution). The words can be placed in any of the directions (horizontal, vertical, diagonal)

Can someone throw some pointers to achieve it in HTML?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will do the job

HTML

```
<div class="solutionline" style="width:Npx;transform:rotate(Ndeg)"></div>
```

css

```
.solutionline{

border-radius:5px;
height:15px;
background:transparent;
border:2px solid black;

}
```

good luck on your project

Comment: Thank you. It looks promising! Will try it.

Comment: It looks like I can not use "div" within <td><body>
    <table align='center'>
        <tr >
            <td>  <div class="solutionline" style="width:80px;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)"></div>i</td>
            <td>t</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>